Are test functions always required when integrating over distributions?
Consider a Gaussian measure $\mu$ over the space of tempered distributions $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Such a measure is constructed by using cylinder setse of the form
$$C_{d; f_1, \ldots, f_d} = \Bigg\{\phi \in \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n): \big(\phi(f_1), \phi(f_2), \ldots, \phi(f_n)\Big) \in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)\Bigg\}$$
where $d$ can be any natural number, $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ denotes the Borel sets on $\mathbb{R}^d$, and $f_i \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.
The measure $\mu$ allows us to integrate over tempered distributions. However, we can only integrate over scalar valued functions and also products of distributions such as $\phi^n$ are not well defined. This leads me to believe we can only carry out integrals of the form
$$\int_{\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)} F(\phi)d\mu(\phi)$$
where $F$ is a function of $\phi$ such that it it always has inside it a fixed test function. For example, we may take $F(\phi) = \phi(f)\phi(g)$ where $f, g \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ are fixed as part of the definition of $F$. Similarly, this would imply we cannot integrate without test functions, so integrals of the form
$$\int_{\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)} \phi^2 d\mu(\phi)$$
are not well defined.
I would like to verify that I have understood this correctly.

In general not well defined but if the measure is special, it can be defined by a renormalization procedure. See the introduction of my article "A second-quantized Kolmogorov-Chentsov Theorem via the operator product expansion" https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00220-019-03665-4

@AbdelmalekAbdesselam Thank you. This paper looks like it answers all my questions on products of distributions and even some others I had on Wick products and OPEs. I will read it in detail. Aside from powers of $\phi$, would it be possible to make sense of the first moment $\int_{\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)} \phi d\mu(\phi)$ (or any other integrand consisting only of linear functions of $\phi$) and obtain a scalar as an output without acting on test functions?
